# No DHCP Reply on bridge with QEMU and TAP interface

Tags: networking, dhcp, qemu

I have a host machine running a virtual machine with QEMU and i want the DHCP server on the host providing an IP address to it.

I am using static ethernet addresses for the guests, so i start them up like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -netdev tap,id=n1,ifname=tap0001,script=/root/qemu/net-up.sh,downscript=/root/qemu/net-down.sh -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=n1,mac=02:00:00:01:01:01 -enable-kvm -cdrom /root/qemu/install-amd64-minimal-20180802T214502Z.iso -boot d -enable-kvm -qmp tcp:localhost:4444,server,nowait -smp 2,cores=16,threads=1,sockets=2,maxcpus=32 -m size=1G -vnc :1
```

Since i want to manage host reservations via a database I am using Kea DHCP server with MySQL Backend.

After starting up the VM I have the following network setup:

```
Host:
eno1: 10.0.0.1 (listening for dhcp requests)
tap0001: no IP (TAP interface for the VM)
br00001: no IP (bridges tap0001 and eno1)

Guest:
eth0: hw ether 02:00:00:01:01:01
```

Now, when I request an IP from the host i can see Kea offering the configured IP:

```
2018-08-15 23:13:46.536 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/6548] DHCP4_LEASE_ADVERT [hwtype=1 02:00:00:01:01:01], cid=[ff:00:01:01:01:00:01:00:01:23:07:53:2b:02:00:00:01:01:01], tid=0xf069f396: lease 10.0.0.10 will be advertised
2018-08-15 23:14:51.444 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/6548] DHCP4_LEASE_ADVERT [hwtype=1 02:00:00:01:01:01], cid=[ff:00:01:01:01:00:01:00:01:23:07:53:2b:02:00:00:01:01:01], tid=0xf069f396: lease 10.0.0.10 will be advertised
```

I can also see the DHCP discover and reply on eno1:

```
tcpdump port 67 or port 68 -i eno1 -nN
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:11:41.326945 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 02:00:00:01:01:01, length 356
23:11:41.329444 IP 10.0.0.1.67 > 10.0.0.10.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 307
```

But the DHCP Reply cannot be seen on br0001 neither on tap0001:

```
tcpdump port 67 or port 68 -i br0001 -nN
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on br0001, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

23:26:33.308296 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 02:00:00:01:01:01, length 356
23:26:37.336875 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 02:00:00:01:01:01, length 356
```

Could somebody point me into the right direction, so that DHCP replies will be sent over to the VM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have assigned your IP to eno1.

Generally if you use a bridge your IP should be assigned to the bridge itself and not the first interface you add to the bridge.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86056/why-does-linux-require-moving-ip-from-eth-interface-to-bridge-interface